# How many Terms/Variables/Constraints/Non-Zeroes I defined in my Solver Foundation model?

Tags: c#, constraint-programming, ms-solver-foundation

I'm using `Microsoft Solver Foundation Express` eddition in my program, Express version is limited in model size according [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff524499(v=VS.93).aspx#Anchor_2).

Is there any way to find how many:

- Terms
- Variables
- Constraints
- Non-Zeros

I defined in my model, using code?

Comment: @Backs: What is my question do you think, so?

Comment: @Backs: To me, it is a perfectly valid programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.services.model%28v=vs.93%29.aspx) class maintains `Decisions` and `Constraints` as collections. You could enumerate those and count them.

To keep track of your `Term` variables, you could create and count them by your own constructor method.

**Example:**

```
static Term NewTerm(Term t)
{
    noOfTerms++;   //  defined as class variable somewhere else
    return t;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var context = SolverContext.GetContext();
    var model = context.CreateModel();
    double sqrt2 = Math.Sqrt(2.0);

    var t = new Decision(Domain.RealRange(-sqrt2, +sqrt2), "t");
    var u = new Decision(Domain.RealRange(-2 * sqrt2, +2 * sqrt2), "u");

    model.AddDecisions(t, u);

    Term P = NewTerm(2 * t * t / (3 * t * t + u * u + 2 * t) - (u * u + t * t) / 18);

    model.AddGoal("objective", GoalKind.Maximize, P);

    Console.WriteLine("Constraints: " + model.Constraints.Count());
    Console.WriteLine("Decisions:   " + model.Decisions.Count());
    Console.WriteLine("Goals:       " + model.Goals.Count());
    Console.WriteLine("Terms:       " + noOfTerms);

    Solution sol = context.Solve();
    Report report = sol.GetReport();
    Console.WriteLine(report);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

You are probably aware that *Microsoft* does no longer actively promote the *Microsoft Solver Foundation*.

Comment: Thanks, you said "To keep track of your Term ....", could you please explain more with piece of code, maybe?

Comment: Yeah I know that Microsoft does no longer activity promote the MSF, whats your suggestion for its replacement?

Comment: [Minizinc](http://www.minizinc.org/) and/or Gecode might be worth looking at. Also, SMT solvers like Z3 or Clasp could be useful.

Comment: Another candidate could be [Google OR Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/).

Comment: Can I check how many non-zeros my model has? Because in my case, it's giving me an error: Model size limit has been exceeded for this version of the product. Please contact Microsoft Corporation for licensing options.
Limits: NonzeroLimit = 100000, MipVariableLimit = 2000, MipRowLimit = 2000, MipNonzeroLimit = 10000, CspTermLimit = 25000, Expiration = none.

I need to check which limit has exceeded.

@AxelKemper

Comment: @AmitMadan: You probably have to count the variables while creating/adding them. My answer shows how to count `Term` objects. In a similar fashion, you could wrap the `Decision` creation and count in the wrapper function.